# Spring MVC configuration and directory structure

Tags: spring-mvc

I am a core java developer trying to learn Spring MVC framework for getting a job. I searched a lot but not able to find tutorial for understanding Spring MVC configuration and directory structure setup from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

here you go, they helped me get started:

https://www.gontu.org/spring-mvc-tutorials/